# Fill Series Dynamic Range in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a range of dates with some missing and I am trying to use the Fill Series tool in a macro to get a full list of dates. When using the Fill Series tool you can't reference a cell in the stop value and this prevents me from having a dynamic range based on the data set.

```
Sub Test()
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Range("A1").Select
    Selection.DataSeries Rowcol:=xlColumns, Type:=xlLinear, Date:=xlDay, _
        Step:=1, Stop:=.Range("F1"), Trend:=False
End Sub
```

This is what I tried doing but you can't use `Stop:=.Range("F1")`. Is there anyway to reference a cell here or do you have to use an integer.

By no means am I good at coding so I appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: I think your problem is the `.` in front of `Range`.

Answer (score 1):

Pls. try this

```
Sub Test()
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Range("A1").Select
    Selection.DataSeries Rowcol:=xlColumns, Type:=xlChronological, Date:=xlDay, _
        Step:=1, Stop:=Range("F1"), Trend:=False
End Sub
```

If your ActiveCell is in the column A you will get an Application Error.

That cell (one left to the ActiveCell when the Sub starts) should contain the starting date from which you want to fill the column till the F1 value.